# Is it appropriate to phrase the sentence like this to avoid ending on a preposition?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

I am once again pondering about whether this sentence is incorrect or not. The sentence in question is:

[*There are some subjects no amount of studying will prepare you for*.]

I remember reading that i should avoid ending clauses with prepositions, and because of that i thought i could change the sentence to this:

[*There are some subjects for which no amount of studying will prepare you*.]

But now i can't tell if this is better or worse.

Answer (score 1):

Ending with a preposition isn’t wrong. It’s less formal. The so-called 'rule' about never ending a sentence with a preposition is not really a rule. There has been, for about 100 years now, near unanimity in this regard from usage guides. It is supposed to have arisen in the 17th and 18th centuries when some scholars believed that English should be more closely aligned with Latin.

> It would appear that some people are determined to hold on to this
> rule, no matter how many times they are informed that it really isn’t
> one.

[Ending a sentence with a preposition (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/prepositions-ending-a-sentence-with)

You may encounter teachers, editors, etc, who cling to the outdated notion, and, to avoid arguments, in formal writing you may wish to choose to avoid terminal prepositions, as you have in the second of your two example sentences.

[Ending sentence with prepositions (Australian Manual of Style)](https://stylemanual.com.au/contents/editing/grammar/common-grammar-questions/ending-sentences-preposition)

Comment: Yes, this "rule" is now deprecated, made up over 100 years ago with no real logical basis. As they say, "Never end a sentence with with"

Comment: Your first version isn't grammatically wrong, as Michael and Peter have said, but the second is better in formal usage.